# How to update intents using python SDK API.AI?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am new to api.ai
I want to update the user says sections in my intents using python sdk support.

I have followed the instructions given [docs.api.ai](https://docs.api.ai/docs/intents#put-intentsiid) using this method removes my previous `user says` data.

how can I update `user say` so that my previous `user say` data remains unchanged?

Comment: were you able to find a way to do that? I am also looking at the way to update/create intent through python SDK but couldn't find any relevant examples

Comment: I haven't find any method but if I find i will share

Answer (score 0):

You can check [flask-assistant](http://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a python framework that makes it easy to build API.AI webhooks with python and flask.